# How to run a Python project (package) on AWS EMR serverless?

Tags: amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I have a Python project with several modules, classes, and dependencies files (a `requirements.txt` file). I want to pack it into one file with all the dependencies and give the file path to AWS EMR serverless, which will run it.

The problem is that I don't understand how to pack a Python project with all the dependencies, which file the EMR can consume, etc. All the examples I have found used one Python file.

In simple words, what should I do if my Python project is not a single file but is more complex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this with EMR Serverless. Regardless of which way you choose, you will need to provide a main entrypoint Python script to the EMR Serverless StartJobRun command.

Let's assume you've got a job structure like this where `main.py` is your entrypoint that creates a Spark session and runs your jobs and `job1` and `job2` are your local modules.

```
├── jobs
│   └── job1.py
│   └── job2.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
```

#### Option 1. Use `--py-files` with your zipped local modules and `--archives` with a packaged virtual environment for your external dependencies

- Zip up your job files

```
zip -r job_files.zip jobs
```

- Create a virtual environment using `venv-pack` with your dependencies.

> Note: This has to be done with a similar OS and Python version as EMR Serverless, so I prefer using a multi-stage Dockerfile with custom outputs.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2 AS base

RUN yum install -y python3

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install venv-pack==0.2.0 && \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /output && venv-pack -o /output/pyspark_deps.tar.gz

FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=base /output/pyspark_deps.tar.gz /
```

If you run `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --output . .`, you should now have a `pyspark_deps.tar.gz` file on your local system.

- Upload `main.py`, `job_files.zip`, and `pyspark_deps.tar.gz` to a location on S3.
- Run your EMR Serverless job with a command like this (replacing `APPLICATION_ID`, `JOB_ROLE_ARN`, and `YOUR_BUCKET`):

```bash
aws emr-serverless start-job-run \
    --application-id $APPLICATION_ID \
    --execution-role-arn $JOB_ROLE_ARN \
    --job-driver '{
        "sparkSubmit": {
            "entryPoint": "s3://<YOUR_BUCKET>/main.py",
            "sparkSubmitParameters": "--py-files s3://<YOUR_BUCKET>/job_files.zip --conf spark.archives=s3://<YOUR_BUCKET>/pyspark_deps.tar.gz#environment --conf spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python --conf spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python --conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python"
        }
    }'
```

#### Option 2. Package your local modules as a Python library and use `--archives` with a packaged virtual environment

This is probably the most reliable way, but it will require you to use [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/). You can use a simple `pyproject.toml` file along with your existing `requirements.txt`

```ini
[project]
name = "mysparkjobs"
version = "0.0.1"
dynamic = ["dependencies"]
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}
```

You then can use a multi-stage Dockerfile and [custom build outputs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs) to package your modules and dependencies into a virtual environment.

> Note: This requires you to enable [Docker Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/#getting-started)

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2 AS base

RUN yum install -y python3

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install venv-pack==0.2.0 && \
    python3 -m pip install .

RUN mkdir /output && venv-pack -o /output/pyspark_deps.tar.gz

FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=base /output/pyspark_deps.tar.gz /
```

Now you can run `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --output . .` and a `pyspark_deps.tar.gz` file will be generated with all your dependencies. Upload this file and your `main.py` script to S3.

Assuming you uploaded both files to `s3://<YOUR_BUCKET>/code/pyspark/myjob/`, run the EMR Serverless job like this (replacing the `APPLICATION_ID`, `JOB_ROLE_ARN`, and `YOUR_BUCKET`:

```bash
aws emr-serverless start-job-run \
    --application-id <APPLICATION_ID> \
    --execution-role-arn <JOB_ROLE_ARN> \
    --job-driver '{
        "sparkSubmit": {
            "entryPoint": "s3://<YOUR_BUCKET>/code/pyspark/myjob/main.py",
            "sparkSubmitParameters": "--conf spark.archives=s3://<YOUR_BUCKET>/code/pyspark/myjob/pyspark_deps.tar.gz#environment --conf spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python --conf spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python --conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python"
        }
    }'
```

Note the additional `sparkSubmitParameters` that specify your dependencies and configure the driver and executor environment variables for the proper paths to `python`.

Comment: you may want to also check this official AWS samples repo where this example is taken from: https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-serverless-samples/tree/main/examples/pyspark/dependencies