# AWS EMR serverless - how to submit pyspark jobs (using console) with multiple files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr-serverless

Hi i am new to EMR serverless and trying to learn. I have a pyspark project which i want to run using EMR serverless. I tried using console but it is not letting me provide folder location as input. i can submit only one file , and when i try that - it complains about missing dependencies ( other .py files). Can someone please share steps?
TYIA

Tried to run with main file, however it failed complaining about dependencies missing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the structure of your project and the type of dependencies you have.

If your project just has multiple `.py` files and no external dependencies, you can upload those files to S3 and pass them to the job using the `spark.submit.pyFiles` Spark property. *One thing to be aware of here is that if your local project is structured with directories, you'll need to zip up those files and upload the zip instead.*

First, if your just have a flat structure, you upload both your main PySpark script and the additional Python files to S3.

```
.
├── job1.py
└── main.py

1 directory, 2 files
```

You can do this use `aws s3 sync`:

```bash
aws s3 sync . s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/prefix/
```

Then, when you create your EMR Serverless job in the console, you provide `s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/prefix/main.py` as the script location, and in the "Spark properties" section, you add `spark.submit.pyFiles` with a comma-separated list of your `.py` files.

```
spark.submit.pyFiles       s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/prefix/job1.py
```

If you have your modules in directories, you'll need to zip up those directories, upload them to S3 and provide the zip file as the path to `spark.submit.pyFiles`. **It's very important to have `__init__.py` in your directories for Python/PySpark to recognize them as modules.**

```
.
├── jobs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── job1.py
└── main.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

If you have `zip` installed locally:

```bash
zip -r jobs.zip jobs
aws s3 cp main.py s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/prefix/
aws s3 cp jobs.zip s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/prefix/
```

```
spark.submit.pyFiles       s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/prefix/jobs.zip
```

If you're using third-party dependencies, check out this other similar question: [How to run a Python project (package) on AWS EMR serverless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74193417/how-to-run-a-python-project-package-on-aws-emr-serverless)

Finally, there's also a new [`emr-cli`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-emr-cli) project under development that makes deploying and running a job on EMR Serverless as easy as one command. It will automatically detect the additional `.py` files, zip them up, upload them to S3 and provide the right parameters to EMR Serverless.

```bash
emr run \
        --application-id <APPLICATION_ID> \
        --job-role arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<JOB_ROLE> \
        --s3-code-uri s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<PREFIX> \
        --entry-point main.py \
        --build --wait
```